Is subtraction on the reals isomorphic to division on the positive reals?
I know that the magma $(\mathbb{R};+)$ of addition on the real numbers is isomorphic to the magma $(\mathbb{R}^+;\times)$ of multiplication on the strictly positive real numbers. I wonder, is it the case that the magma $(\mathbb{R};-)$ of subtraction on the real numbers is isomorphic to the magma $(\mathbb{R};\div)$ of division on the strictly positive real numbers? Since subtraction is the inverse operation to addition, and division is the inverse operation to multiplication, I expect that they are isomorphic.

Yes, and the proof is the same, you take logarithms. This already follows from the fact that the first isomorphism you name is an isomorphism of groups, so it's compatible with both addition and additive inverse, hence with subtraction.
